# MVC what is the best way to edit multiple record at one go in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

what is the best practice to edit multiple record in MVC ?
I have surf the net for while now but cant find a good answer for it.

for now my solution look like this in controller:

```
for (int i = 0; i < customer.Count();i++)
            {
                Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
                id = new Guid(customer[i]);
                try
                {
                    CustomerProduct customerProduct = customerProductRepository.GetCustomerProductByCustomeridAndProductID(id,productID);


                    customerProductRepository.DbContext.BeginTransaction();

                    customerProduct.ProductVersion = productVersionRepository.Get(productVersionId);

                    customerProduct = customerProductRepository.SaveOrUpdate(customerProduct);
                    customerProductRepository.DbContext.CommitTransaction();
                    TempData["toastType"] = "success";
                    TempData["message"] = customerProduct.Customer.Name+" is been successful updated";

                 }
                catch
                {

                    TempData["toastType"] = "error";
                    TempData["message"] = "An Error occurred, Please try again later";
                    customerRepository.DbContext.RollbackTransaction();
                    return View(model);
                }
            }
```

it is possible to rollback 10 Transaction ? if the first 5 been commit it and the six record failed to commit due to some reason. 
Thank you

Comment: in your situation instead of looping in controller try looping in database instead..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `CustomerProductRepository` have a AddAll/UpdateAll method which will look like below code:

```
public void AddAll<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) where T : class
{
    Guard.ArgumentNotNull(items, "items");

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Set<T>().Add(item);
    }

    SaveChanges();
}
```

SaveChanges gets called only when all items are added successfully. The DB will perform a bulk update and you will get better performance.